# why isn't my css font changing?

Tags: css, html

```css
#who {
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #f91845;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  top: 200px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="who">
  <h1 class="tlt">Who am I?</h1>
</div>
```

I also tried the below one because the one above is not working:

```
h1:first-child{
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

Please let me know why the font isn't changing? If I use h1:first-child, the font is getting applied to all h1 elements.

Comment: Your code works well https://jsfiddle.net/e9t6adpd/ .... Then oly thing I can see wrong is your "comments" in the code aren't properly formatted and also on CSS you don't use `<!---` to comment instead use `/* --- */`

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, I haven't entered any comments in my original file. Code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi please clarify your question you write **this is getting applied to all the h1's on page** but later **I'm unable to give font size to any element**

Comment: I edited it. I hope my question is clarified. Thanks.

Comment: Now is clear. You can't change the font-size form the definition of the ID as the other properties because `#who` is the div parent and **H1** elements by default doesn't inherit the font-size, they already have a predefined font-size set. If you want to apply that to just the h1 inside who use `#who h1`

Comment: Thanks Dan. Issue resolved.

Comment: Glad to help U :) ... Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

try

```
.tlt
{
font-size:70px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser applies two sets of CSS to the page: the *user agent* styles (the browser “defaults”) and the *author* styles (yours).

The user agent styles set things like heading font sizes. These target the `<h1>` directly and set a font size, usually about `2em`.

Your styles target the parent element `#who`. Some properties, such as the font properties *inherit* down the DOM to the `<h1>`, but declarations that target the `<h1>` directly will override those inherited values. The User Agent styles are targeting the `<h1>` are doing this.

If you want to override the user agent styles, you need to target the `<h1>` as well. This is why something like this works:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See, h1 is inside div of id who. Now, if you set font size of #who div then h1 should have it's font size but in the application there would be some font-size of h1 already defined; so it would override #who div's font-size.

```
h1:first-child
```

This will target all first child of any other containers. So, ideally this won't be a right method.

```
#who h1{font-size:70px;}
```

This would do solve your problem.

Now if you wanna target first child h1 of #who div then use following css

```
#who h1:first-child{font-size:70px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because if your code is exactly what you have posted you dont use id selector in your css.
for more information please read 
[W3 CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

According to updated question:
Applying to all h1's is also related to that
since you are not referencing h1 inside 'who' id it selects all of them. Because every h1 is first child of another element

Can you please change

```
h1:first-child
```

to

`#who h1:first-child`